# Unable to set Window State to Exclusive in Struts2 Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, struts2, liferay, portlet

Overview: Porting a struts2 web-appp to liferay struts2 6.2 portlet

Issue: Unable to set windowState to be "Exclusive" in the the struts2 tag `<s:url ..../>`

Description:I need to set windowState to be "Exclusive" in the the struts2 tag `<s:url ..../>`.

I am trying the below option but not able to set url's window state as exclusive.

```xml
<s:url var="billingOverview" action="%{billingOverviewURL}"
       portletMode="view" portletUrlType="struts.portlet.action"
       windowState=<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString()%> />
```

Initially I got the exception: "according to tld or attribute windowState, does not accept any expressions".I modified the struts2 core jar(struts2-core-2.3.7.jar)'s "struts-tags.tld"  file , in which I made the below changes to accept the expressions as well in the windowState tag by changing rtexprvalue as TRUE:

```xml
<attribute>
      <description><![CDATA[The resulting portlet window state]]></description>
      <name>windowState</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

It would be really great if I can get some pointer on above issue. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest scriptlets (`<%...%>` that you should not use anywhere else) inside Struts tags.

You need to <strike>enable static method access in struts.xml</strike>

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
```

and then reference the FQCN with the following syntax:

Change it to:

```xml
<s:url portletUrlType="struts.portlet.action"
          portletMode="view" 
                  var="billingOverview" 
               action="%{billingOverviewURL}"   
          windowState="%{@com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState@EXCLUSIVE}" />
```

More on [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties).

Comment: No need for allowing static method access to get a static field.

Comment: @AleksandrM always fooled by the doc: `OGNL supports accessing static properties as well as static methods.

By default, Struts 2 is configured to disallow this--to enable OGNL's static **member** support you must set the struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess constant to true via any of the Constant Configuration methods.` but I guess you're right... can't remember because I've it pretty much always to true, btw the name of the property suggests you are right :)

Comment: I will just try this out and will update ..thx for your replies :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I have figured out that in the struts.xml `allowStaticMethodAccess` value was already set to true, if I set it to false other web pages data becomes inconsistent. Nevetheless, I tried making it false and setting the windowState as you mentioned above , but the url which is formed is still "normal" i.e. `p_p_state=normal`. So the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @TechieTalk : leave out the allowStatichMethodAccess from the game, it should be irrelevant (leave it to `true`). Which version of Struts are you using ? Can you post the generated HTML with the url ?